# Trying to make a readable txt file from an np array, all printing on one line?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, save

I have searched various questions on here, but am unable to find an adequate solution to how to save my array to be readable in a text file. I have a numpy array with shape (13,5) that contains strings . When I use np.savetxt, it all prints on one line.

More array info: type: class 'numpy.ndarray', type of entries: class 'numpy.str_'.

Here is the line I use to print my array:

```
np.savetxt('file_name.txt', array_name, fmt="%s")
```

Why does it print on one line? How can I make it print in an easy to read fashion (not all on one line)?

```
array_name=np.array(
[['Champion' 'Wins' 'Plays' 'Win %' 'Popularity'],
['Ahri' '17' '25' '68.0' '1.25'],
['Akali' '4' '7' '57.14' '0.35'],
['Alistar' '28' '56' '50.0' '2.8'],
['Amumu' '3' '4' '75.0' '0.2'],
['Anivia' '5' '6' '83.33' '0.3'],
['Annie' '1' '9' '11.11' '0.45'],
['Ashe' '7' '11' '63.64' '0.55'],
['Azir' '16' '28' '57.14' '1.4'],
['Bard' '19' '34' '55.88' '1.7'],
['Blitzcrank' '9' '16' '56.25' '0.8'],
['Brand' '0' '1' '0.0' '0.05'],
['Braum' '5' '16' '31.25' '0.8']])
```

Comment: can you provide the example output you want? what would be easy to read for you?

Comment: Can you please provide more code. Like what is in the array ?

Comment: A copy-n-paste from an interacitve session would helpful - I'd like to see `array_name.shape`, `array_name.dtype`, and a portion of `repr(array_name)`.  Maybe also a clip from the file.  The only reason I can think for a 1line is a `(1,n)` shape.  Or maybe the n/l aren't registering on your display.

Comment: The other question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599284, suggests that viewing the file with Windows `notepad` might be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, now that you've provided a sample array, it's easy to see why you get the result you describe: you don't have commas separating what are supposed to be distinct strings in each row. Python concatenates adjacent string literals:

```
>>> 'a' 'b' 'c'
'abc'
```

Thus your array has 1 column, not 5:

```
>>> array_name.shape
(13, 1)

>>> array_name[0, 0]
'ChampionWinsPlaysWin %Popularity'

>>> array_name[0, 1]
IndexError          Traceback...
...
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, more info needed -- I can't reproduce what you describe. After running this:

```
import numpy as np
ra = np.array([['Here', 'is', 'my'],
               ['array', 'of', 'strings']])
np.savetxt('temp.txt', ra, fmt="%s")
```

the file `temp.txt` contains:

```
Here is my
array of strings
```

One line per row, each ending with `'\n'`, with items in each row separated by spaces.

Comment: This is what I would like, but for some reason, mine is not doing that.