# Why doesn't my array space correctly when I use np.savetxt

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Why doesn't the text file space the output correctly?

```
import numpy as np
my_list =['str1', 'str2', 'str3']
my_list2=[1,2,3]
print(my_list)
```

['str1', 'str2', 'str3'] is printed.

```
my_array=np.array(my_list)
my_array2=np.array(my_list2)
combined=np.column_stack([my_array,my_array2])
np.savetxt('test_file_name.txt', combined, fmt="%s")
print(combined)
```

The print gives:

```
[['str1' '1']

['str2' '2']

['str3' '3']]
```

The file says `str1 1str2 2str3 3`.
I want it to say:

```
str1 1

str2 2

str3 3
```

Running Windows 8.1, using notepad to view file.

Short Answer: Notepad is the worst. Use notepad++.

Appending a question: Is there a way to have the columns line up nicer? Some of my data has only a few characters, while others are have fifteen or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you print the array you will not see the commas which is the normal behaviour numpy, if  you use `repr` when printing i.e `print repr(np.array([1, 2, 3]))` or run it from a python shell or ipython without printing it will also show the `repr` which is what you see in the scipy docs.

There is no difference at all whether you see the repr output or the formatted output, the array shape does not change so that has nothing to do with your issue:

```
In [13]: a
Out[13]: 
array(['1', '2', '3'],  # repr
      dtype='|S1')

In [14]: b
Out[14]: 
array(['2', '3', '4'], # repr
      dtype='|S1')

In [15]: print(a) # str
['1' '2' '3']

In [16]: print(b) # str
['2' '3' '4']

In [17]: print(np.column_stack((a,b)))
[['1' '2']
 ['2' '3']
 ['3' '4']]
```

If you are having issues with `column_stack`, it is not because of how the arrays look when you print them.

Your output would also be exactly as you want it in your file:

```
str1 1
str2 2
str3 3
```

The only way I see you getting `str1 1str2 2str3 3` in the file is if you actually used `newline=""` so all the data would end up on a single line.

Comment: when i use savetxt to save it to a text file it prints all on one line ( i will show more code)

Comment: save the info to a text file, and have it spaced as you see in the print statement (without brackets or quotes)

Comment: I am using numpy version 1.9.2.

Comment: And your python version and OS?

Comment: I did not use newline. I type in exactly the code I have above and that is the output.

Comment: @Mark,  what OS and are you testing using the example data in the question?

Comment: Could there be a mismatch between the newline that `savetxt` is using, and what the file reader (editor, shell, etc) expects?  `'2str3'` sure looks like a newline is missing or not understood.

Comment: @Mark, open the file with notepad++ if possible, http://superuser.com/questions/362087/notepad-ignoring-linebreaks

Comment: @hpaulj, based on the edit I think you are on the right lines, the OP is using notepad to open the files

Comment: @Mark, adding `newline="\r\n"` may show the correct output in notepad also, don't use windows so not totally sure